# Batch Get String between 2 characters

Tags: batch-file, substring

I have a text file with a content similar like this:

#### `test.txt`:

> ```
> FIPS job <1532602344643_1>  of size <134> successfully created.
> <134>  files successfully exported.
> <0>  files failed.
> ```

I want to store the string between the first two angle brackets in a variable. In this example it is `1532602344643_1`. The string should have the same length but in all other brackets the length could change.

Im new to this so can someone help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hint: take a look at [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) and set the tokens and delimiters properly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the batch file that do what you need:

```
@echo off
set TEXT_FILE=text.txt
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set modules=
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (%TEXT_FILE%) do (
  set "tmp=%%~i"
  set modulesFromLine=
  call :getNext modulesFromLine "!tmp!"
  if "-!modules!"=="-" (
    set modules=!modulesFromLine!
  ) else (
    set modules=!modules!,!modulesFromLine!
  )
)
endlocal & set REZULT=%modules%&
echo. %REZULT%
exit /b 0

:getNext
setlocal
  set accumulator=
  set "tmp=%~2"
  set "tmp=!tmp:*<=!"
  set "tail=>!tmp:*>=!"
  call set "module_name=%%tmp:!tail!=%%"
  if not "-!module_name!"=="-" (
    call :getNext %1 "!tail!"
    if "-!%1!"=="-" (
      set "accumulator=!module_name!"
    ) else (
      set "accumulator=!module_name!,!%1!"
    )
  )
endlocal & set %1=%accumulator%&
exit /b 0
```

Put your file to `TEXT_FILE` and take `RESULT`. Remember that string should not contain `"`.

If you want to read someting about batch [wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting#FOR) is good for start.